# spring data elasticsearch 7 class not found exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I want to use spring data elasticsearch with elastic docker 7.2

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch'
```

but when spring boot app runs this error appears:

```
2019-07-20 12:35:38.564 ERROR 21804 --- [           main] .d.e.r.s.AbstractElasticsearchRepository : failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{aD43cDv-QnG1e16fnU0dsQ}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}]
```

and in elasticsearch log

```
Received message from unsupported version: [6.4.3] minimal compatible version is: [6.8.0]
```

I use gradle then I add `ext['elasticsearch.version'] = '7.2.0'` now error changes

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'instagramUserRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/action/admin/indices/mapping/put/PutMappingResponse
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'instagramUserRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/action/admin/indices/mapping/put/PutMappingResponse
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1111) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.cacheRepositoryFactory(Repositories.java:97) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.populateRepositoryFactoryInformation(Repositories.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.<init>(Repositories.java:83) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter.setApplicationContext(DomainClassConverter.java:109) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration.addFormatters(SpringDataWebConfiguration.java:131) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerComposite.addFormatters(WebMvcConfigurerComposite.java:81) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.addFormatters(DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.java:78) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.mvcConversionService(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:476) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1f0f7b64.CGLIB$mvcConversionService$1(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1f0f7b64$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$60445fb2.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1f0f7b64.mvcConversionService(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/action/admin/indices/mapping/put/PutMappingResponse
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:184) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$getTargetRepositoryViaReflection$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:513) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:513) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:498) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:74) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:305) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:67) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 72 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/action/admin/indices/mapping/put/PutMappingResponse
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.putMapping(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:249) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.putMapping(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:233) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.putMapping(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:228) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.putMapping(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:100) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.<init>(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:88) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.<init>(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:36) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 85 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.mapping.put.PutMappingResponse
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    ... 96 common frames omitted
```

I test elasticsearch.version=6.8.1 too but nothing change.
Is there any possible way to use spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch with elasticsearch 7.2.0

Comment: i think this is because of some version conflicts

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch 7.x still not supported by spring-data-elasticsearch.
Last stable release is for Elasticsearch 6.2.2 as of July 2019

See compatibility matrix: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch#maven-configuration

Comment: yes I see that but how to use snapshot version in gradle.

Comment: I set snapshot repository and change version of library. gradle sync successfully but all imports of elasticsearch give error like ElasticsearchRepository

Comment: I think 6.8.1 is the maximum version you can use with snapshot release

Comment: elasticsearch log said `Received message from unsupported version: [6.4.3] minimal compatible version is: [6.8.0]` then 6.8.1 is must work

Answer (score 0):

The conflict I was having was related to Actuator :
spring-boot-actuatorautoconfigure

As soon as I removed that dependency ... all went fine ! FWIW